# Can name/external credentials handle wrapped jwt?

Tags: namedcredentials, jwt, externalcredentials

the endpoint I'm authenticating with returns a Json response which contains the Jwt as a property of the Json. For example...

```
{
   "id":"1234567890",
   "jwt": "Json token here hjsdfgJYHGjnjdashjgsdaj....",
   "date": "2024-03-14..."
}
```

Is it possible to get the jwt token from the jwt property avbove?

Comment: Named Credentials - no, you have to do it yourself in Apex. You might be able to use the [new Apex classes](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_apex_nc.htm&release=248&type=5) that were very recently introduced as part of [token exchange flow](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_security_token_exchange.htm&release=248&type=5) support.

Comment: @identigral, this is a valuable reply - a pity you don't put it in a StackExchange answer!

Comment: @FelixvanHove You're making a value judgement, our measurement scales are different.